# Need of optimized code for hide and show div in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div:

```
<div id="p1" class="img-projects" style="margin-left:0;">
  <a href="project1.php"> <img src="image1.png"/></a>
  <div id="p1" class="project-title">Bar Crawler</div>
</div>
```

On mouse-over I want to add an image with opacity and make the project-title shown.
So I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.project-title').hide();

            $('#p1.img-projects img').mouseover(
               function() {
                   $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 800);
                   $('#p1.project-title').fadeIn(500);
            });
            $('#p1.img-projects img').mouseout(
               function() {
                   $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 800);
                   $('#p1.project-title').fadeOut();
            });


            $('#p2.img-projects img').mouseover(
               function() {
                   $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 800);
                   $('#p2.project-title').fadeIn(500);
            });
            $('#p2.img-projects img').mouseout(
               function() {
                   $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 800);
                   $('#p2.project-title').fadeOut();
            });

    });

</script>
```

The code works fine but does anyone know a way to optimize my code?

Thank you

Comment: You are lucky that it works. IDs must be unique in a HTML document.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function for everything that's relative not ID dependent, like this:

```
$('.img-projects img').hover(function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, 800)
          .closest('.img-projects').find('.project-title').fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 800)
          .closest('.img-projects').find('.project-title').fadeOut();
});
```

This finds all elements relative to the one that was hovered instead of having a different function to handle each one...you could probably remove the IDs from your elements as well unless they serve another purpose.  Since currently you have invalid HTML with the ID being used twice each time, this resolves that as well.

Comment: Hi,
the ".find" it does not work like this. Maybe is $(this).find??

Comment: I think you need to remove the semicolons in the first line. The `closest` call is supposed to chain to the line before.

Comment: I added it to this 
$(this).closest....But yes if I delete the semicolon is better.
Thanks again